# Using Devise and I can't see user id when I'm not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using `devise` and I have a problem with finding user ids when I'm not logged in. How can I direct them to specific user id if I'm not logged in?

```
<h1>Users</h1>
<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= link_to user.user, user_profile_path %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are wanting. You want to find the id of a user? That would be `user.id`. To direct them to a user profile page, then use `user_profile_path(user)`

Comment: yes I'm trying to go to user profile when I'm not log in. I didn't put restriction on that

Comment: Can you post your user controller and database code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Devise provides a route or a controller to handle that.  You can either:

1. Add a new route within the `devise_scope` and override `RegistrationsController#edit`
2. Just make your own custom users controller / routes / views - this makes much more sense IMO